# Call Node.js Script from React component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

```
   const pythonProcess = spawn('python',["tiqi.py", "textFile.txt"]);
    
        pythonProcess.stdout.on('data',(data)=>{
            console.log(data.toString());
        })
```

Can I call and run that code by clicking a component button in my react project?

Comment: If this is server-side code then your client-side code would likely make an AJAX request to a server-side resource to invoke the operation.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `node`-based functions in a browser environment, to do such a thing in a proper way you should build an HTTP/HTTPS API for your `react` application and make requests from `react` to your API.

You can go through by googling building a simple `node` server based on `express`, and output your `python` script results in maybe `.json` file which you'll read with `node` (which will be sent on request from your `react` application).

Hope my answer will help you a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No. But other Node-based functions can be invoked using Browserify.

Refer to this link:
https://github.com/browserify/browserify/issues/1816